# cannot understand my client implementation is not working without goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

I am reading The Go Programming Language book. In section 8.3 we have echo server the code shown below :

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        log.Println("Accepted connection")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }

}
func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    defer c.Close()
    br := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    for br.Scan() {
        echo(c, br.Text(), 1*time.Second)
    }

}

func echo(c net.Conn, shout string, delay time.Duration) {
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToUpper(shout))
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", shout)
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToLower(shout))
}
```

In the book for requesting that server we created netcat clone program as shown below :

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    numberOfCommand := os.Args[1:]
    if len(numberOfCommand) != 3 {
        log.Fatal("Usage: netcat1 <host> <port> <connection-type>")
    }
    host := numberOfCommand[0]
    port := numberOfCommand[1]
    connectionType := numberOfCommand[2]

    conn, err := net.Dial(connectionType, host+":"+port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    go mustCopy(conn, os.Stdin)
    mustCopy(os.Stdout, conn)

}

func mustCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    if _, err := io.Copy(dst, src); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Basically, you are sending some string and the server sends uppercase, normal, and lowercase versions of this string. It is working, but if I remove `go` prefix from the `go mustCopy(conn,os.Stdin)`. It is not working. I think that if I remove the go prefix all things will be done sequentially. It writes a string from stdin to the server and then gets the response, but it is not sending string or getting response.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `mustCopy` does not return until an error, which happens when the connection is closed. So when you call:

```
mustCopy(conn, os.Stdin)
mustCopy(os.Stdout, conn)
```

the first `mustCopy` never returns. It is the one that reads from stdin and writes to the connection. So you are sending requests to the server, but never reading the responses. With `go mustCopy(...)`, the first `mustCopy` runs concurrently in a separate goroutine. The second `mustCopy` blocks until connection terminates, reading the responses, while the first one reads requests from stdin and sends requests.